# Is it possible to make the HTML inside Tippy clickable?

Tags: reactjs, tippyjs

I'm working on a file sharing app. In the dashboard, I want to right click then a context menu appears and I can click on one of the options available in it. I can now display the context menu but it seems I can't click any button or element inside the menu.

Menu Component:

```
import Tippy from "@tippyjs/react/headless"
import { cloneElement, useState } from "react"
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom"
import { followCursor } from "tippy.js"
import "tippy.js/dist/tippy.css"
import Options from "./Options"

type SubMenuProps = {
    children: React.ReactElement
}

const NO_SUBMENU_PATHS = ["/", "/login", "/signup"]

const SubMenu = ({ children }: SubMenuProps) => {
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false)
    const { pathname } = useLocation()

    const child = cloneElement(children, {
        onContextMenu: (e: Event) => {
            e.preventDefault()
            setVisible(!visible)
        },
    })

    if (NO_SUBMENU_PATHS.includes(pathname)) return <>{child}</>

    return (
        <Tippy
            allowHTML
            visible={visible}
            onClickOutside={() => setVisible(false)}
            render={Options}
            followCursor="initial"
            placement="right-start"
            plugins={[followCursor]}
        >
            {child}
        </Tippy>
    )
}

export default SubMenu
```

I tried reading the docs and looking up online but found nothing helpful

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that when initializing the Tippy component you can use the `interactive` attribute and set it to true if you want to click on the popover. Here's the link to the documentation: https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/v6/all-props/#interactive